# Can I add external device or other icons to the desktop?

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, icons

I'm assuming the Unity bar is the bar located on the left hand side of the screen.

Is it possible to move those icons to the desktop, like a shortcut?

I'd like mainly all external device icons, like USB and external drives to be moved, if possible.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use

`gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true`

to get all the mounted volumes on your desktop.

Alternatively, you can install dconf tools with

`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

and navigate to org > nautilus > desktop. Then change `volumes-visible` to checked.

If you'd like to remove the icons from your launcher now that you have them on your desktop, you can install CompizConfig-Settings Manager (CCSM) and change the "Show Devices" option in the "Experimental" tab under "Unity".